# Coordinates relative to arbitrary 3D plane

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, vector-spaces

Say that I have an arbitrary plane, $\mathcal{P}$, in $\mathbb{R}^3$ that is defined by a given vector, $\vec{v}_0$, on the plane and a normal vector, $\vec{n}$.  I will be using $\vec{v}_{0}$ as a sort of focal point in the following description.  Note that $\mathcal{P}$ need not pass through the origin if $\vec{v}_{0}\neq 0$.  I have used the standard equation for the plane, $\vec{n}\cdot (\vec{v}-\vec{v}_0)=0$, to obtain two additional vectors, $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{w}$, such that the set $\{\vec{n}-\vec{v}_{0},\,\vec{u}-\vec{v}_{0},\,\vec{w}-\vec{v}_{0}\}$ is an orthogonal set with respect to the standard dot product.  In other words, I have an orthogonal set of three vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$ which are not located at the origin.

That is, the vectors $\vec{u}-\vec{v}_{0}$ and $\vec{w}-\vec{v}_{0}$ both lie within the plane while $\vec{n}-\vec{v}_{0},\,\vec{u}-\vec{v}_{0}$, and $\vec{w}-\vec{v}_{0}$ are all orthogonal to each other (but not necessarily orthonormal, which I don't think is necessary in this situation).

Now, for a given vector $\vec{v}$ belonging to $\mathcal{P}$, how do I find the coordinates of $\vec{v}-\vec{v}_{0}$ relative to this orthogonal (basis) set $\{\vec{n}-\vec{v}_{0},\,\vec{u}-\vec{v}_{0},\,\vec{w}-\vec{v}_{0}\}$?  These coordinates should therefore be ''along'' and ''out'' of the given plane, $\mathcal{P}$.  Since this plane is 2D, what I am really after are the coordinates of $\vec{v}-\vec{v}_{0}$ relative to both $\vec{u}-\vec{v}_{0}$ and $\vec{w}-\vec{v}_{0}$; i.e., I want to find out where (within this plane, so only two directions needed) that $\vec{v}$ is located relative to $\vec{v}_{0}$.

I am guessing that some combination of change-of-basis and coordinate-transformation will be required.  I am just not sure in what sense but am open to alternative suggestions as well.  It is a fun problem.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to call your basis $\{u_1,u_2,u_3\}$ for brevity. You are trying to express $v-v_0$ as a linear combination of this basis. Thus
$$
v-v_0=c_1u_1+c_2u_2+c_3u_3.
$$
The $c_*$ can be calculated by solving the linear system
$$
\begin{bmatrix}u_1&u_2&u_3\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}c_1\\c_2\\c_3\end{bmatrix}=v-v_0.
$$
You can now exploit the fact that the $u_*$ are orthogonal to solve the system of linear equations. This gives
$$
c_i=\frac{\langle u_i,v-v_0\rangle}{\langle u_i,u_i\rangle},\,i=1,2,3,
$$
where $\langle a,b\rangle=a^Tb$ is the standard Euclidean inner product.

Comment: That's great, thanks!  I arrived at the same answer a few minutes ago, but derived a matrix transformation rather than more elegantly exploiting the orthogonality.